# нужна помощь с aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть бот на aiogram, это кликер. мне нужно, чтобы при введении команды /Minus_limit [число]  из лимита вычиталось то число, которое написано после команды.
надеюсь понятно объяснил..

limit - это переменная

Comment: Что за лимит? Переменная такая что ли?
Можно конкретнее, в чём именно у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Не понятно объяснили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
limit = 0
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Minus_limit'])
async def game(message: types.Message):
    global limit
    args = message.get_args()
    limit -= int(args)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: я ещё никак не могу реализовать баланс 

Comment: может сможете помочь?

Comment: смотря что ты подразумеваешь под этим?